# Show hidden div on ng-click within ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller

`$scope.editPostComment = false;`

When I click on the `btn` it shows the `textarea` in all the repeated item when I want to show it on the clicked div only!

```
 <div class="commentBox" ng-show = "editPostComment" >
                    <textarea name="editor2" class="content-box allfilecomment" id="comment-box" focus-me="{{focusCommentBox}}"
                    ng-model="allCommentText"
                    markdown-editor="{'iconlibrary': 'fa', addExtraButtons: true, resize: 'vertical'}"
                    rows="10" >

                    </textarea>
                    <div class="hints">
                      <span class="boldtext">**Bold**</span>
                      <span class="italictext">_itlaics_</span>
                      <span class="striktext">~~strike~~</span>
                      <span class="codetext">'code'</span>
                      <span class="codetext">'''preformatted'''</span>
                      <span class="quotetext">>quote</span>
                    </div>
                    <div id="comment-btns">
                      <button class="btn btn-primary pull-left" ng-class="{'loading': commentig}" ng-disabled="commentig" ng-click="postAllComment(commentmode)">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: your question is not clear, what is current behavior and what is expected ?

Comment: I hope each div has button . if that is right then use this  to get the clicked div.

Comment: @anoop , @ Himanshu Shekhar as example i have 3 posts generated  by ng-repeat when i click on edit post icon to ng-show textarea on this post it makes the textarea shown on the 3 posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify an id for each row using the index then make the visibility of said row based on that.

```js
function showEdit(id) {
    vm.editPostComment = id;

}
```

```html
 
 
 <div ng-repeat="row in rows track by $index">
     <div class="commentBox" ng-show = "editPostComment == $index" >
         <textarea name="editor2" class="content-box allfilecomment" id="comment-box" focus-me="{{focusCommentBox}}"
                    ng-model="allCommentText"
                    markdown-editor="{'iconlibrary': 'fa', addExtraButtons: true, resize: 'vertical'}"
                    rows="10" >

                    </textarea>
                    <div class="hints">
                      <span class="boldtext">**Bold**</span>
                      <span class="italictext">_itlaics_</span>
                      <span class="striktext">~~strike~~</span>
                      <span class="codetext">'code'</span>
                      <span class="codetext">'''preformatted'''</span>
                      <span class="quotetext">>quote</span>
                    </div>
                    <div id="comment-btns">
                      <button class="btn btn-primary pull-left" ng-class="{'loading': commentig}" ng-disabled="commentig" ng-click="showEdit($index)">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>
```